# Changing HTML image, function doesn't seem to be called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a source to an image through Javascript, and some JQuery code I found on internet, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "http://www.example.com/images/">
        var count=1;
        var initnumber=100;
        function changeImage(){
            count++;
            $("#HTMLPhoto").attr('src'+((initnumber+count).toString)+".jpg");
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="changeImage()" >
    <img id="HTMLPhoto"/>
    <button onclick="changeImage()">Next Image</button>
</body>
```

I am also trying to call once again the `changeImage()` function with button clicks.

Edit:Managed to make it work, I changed the code a bit, if anyone wants to see:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var count=1;
        function nextImage(address){
            count++;
            image = document.getElementById('HTMLPhoto');
            image.src ="http://www.example.com/images/"+(address+count)+".jpg";
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="HTMLPhoto"/>
    <button onclick="nextImage(100)">Next Image</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What makes you think the function isn't called? Can you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: I added the jQuery tag to your question. If that's wrong, please remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#HTMLPhoto").attr('src'+((initnumber+count).toString())+".jpg");
```

To:

```
$("#HTMLPhoto").attr('src', ((initnumber+count).toString())+".jpg");
```

Comment: dont forget that `toString` is a function. must be called `.toString()`

Comment: Also don't forgot to actually include jQuery since the OP doesn't appear to do that.